# C# Regex. Get value attribute from input tag with specific id

Tags: c#, .net, regex, input, tags

Been struggling with this for awhile.  I can't seem to figure out how to get a regex request to only return the value attribute of a particular  html tag.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post sample HTML and explain exactly what you want to extract from it.

Comment: Oh my god, this site has to be renamed RegexOverflow!

Comment: You have a `C#` and a `.net` tag on your question, why don't you just read the value on the postback of the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to parse HTML with Regex? [Don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) or you will continue to struggle. Use [SgmlReader](http://developer.mindtouch.com/en/docs/SgmlReader) or [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

RegEx is not a good solution for parsing unstructured (or unknown) HTML.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) SO post for compelling reasons why this is the case.

I suggest using a parser such as the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and querying the parsed document.